# Sonarqube evaluation - Ant Build failing

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

Updated to reflect Sonar-Runner

We have these projects configured:

[image]

We're using this sonar-project.properties file in the root of the folder containing our application source:

```
sonar.projectKey=Southern
sonar.projectName=Southern
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
```

We run the sonar-runner command in the same folder in which the above properties file exists. We get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.report.ActiveRulesPublishe
r
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Ac
tiveRules
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.rule.ModuleQPro
files
ERROR: Caused by: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.
protobuf?projectKey=Southern
ERROR:
```

The SonarQube application and website are running and available.

Comment: The `sonar.java.libraries` property should point to the directory holding the project's libraries, not the SonarQube platform's libraries.

Comment: Tried pointing it to the project's lib folder and it still failed. Looking to change to using the sonar-runner but there's no sonar-runner exe or cmd file in the install folder's bin folder? It's not an add-on. Is there a separate download for the sonar-runner?

Comment: It is a separate download (as is the Ant task jar, BTW). Check [the scanner docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

Comment: Updated properties file: sonar-sources=src and was able to get a full scan. However the app running via StartSonar.bat keeps terminating so the scan output is not processed. Are there logs anywhere that would indicate why Sonar keeps terminating? It wasn't doing it before. I've had it up for hours, now it shuts down within a minute or so of starting up.

Comment: I found the sonar log and was able to find an error indicating the DB was locked by another process. Maybe one of the many attempts at scanning we ran... I rebooted and the sonar process seems to now stay up. Was able to run scans.

Comment: Resolved with assistance from SonarSource team.

Comment: Add information how to resolve this instead of "resolved" text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded the sonar-runner.

Updated properties file: sonar-sources=src. Scans ran but hung with an error that the DB was locked.

Rebooted the machine and restarted SonarQube. Problem resolved. All scans run.